# I cannot find always on top option in powerToys

Tags: visual-studio-code, stayontop

I want to make VS Code always stay on top by PowerToys, but this option is not there!
Can you help me, please?

I tried other applications, but I want to use PowerToys.

Comment: What do you mean is not there? There is a configurable shortcut for "always on top" feature in PowerToys

Answer (score 0):

By default, this is the "*Always On Top*" shortcut in PowerToys (make sure you have it enabled):

[image]

Just get the focus on your VS Code window and press **⊞+Shift+A**, a red horizontal bar will appear while this feature is active:

[image]